# Execute SELECT statement and get rows of data from SQL Table using BizTalk

Tags: sql-server, xml, biztalk, biztalk-2013

My requirement is to get the input XML file from source and based on one particular input field we need to retrieve multiple rows from database and create those values as segments and append into input XML file and sent to destination folder.

I tried to retrieve the multiple rows from SQL using WCF-SQL adapter but want to know how to append the retrieved values in input xml again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Create a send port using consume adapter service.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd788067.aspx)
2. Use the input xml as a parameter to your select statement which passes into this send port.
3. Use an orchestration which initiates from your input xml and correlates to the response from the send port.
4. Use a dual input map which inputs

   - the input xml
   - the response message which maps to your final message.
5. Send to your final destination.

Comment: Thanks for your help.It worked .

Comment: I can able to get the response from SQL.But for point number 4,the response message which I need to add is having <Any> element.How to get the column values separately and map to final destination

Comment: What is your procedure returning? Are you able to return a record set?

Comment: Now I can able to see the record set after using strong stored procedure